# Failed due to unhealthy allocations - fly.io

Tags: python, hosting, fly

What could be the reason for a Python script failing with "Exit Code: 0" and "Unhealthy allocations" on Fly.io, and how can I troubleshoot it? I'm just trying a host a simple python script on fly.io.

```
#-----python script-----#

import datetime
import time

def periodic_task():
    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        week_number = now.isocalendar()[1]
        print(f"Week number: {week_number}")
        # Sleep for a minute
        time.sleep(5)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    periodic_task()
```

```
#-----fly.toml file-----#

# fly.toml file generated for withered-snowflake-645 on 2023-02-05T04:28:07+05:30

app = "withered-snowflake-645"
kill_signal = "SIGINT"
kill_timeout = 5
processes = []

[build]
  builder = "paketobuildpacks/builder:base"

[env]
  PORT = "8080"

[experimental]
  auto_rollback = true

[[services]]
  http_checks = []
  internal_port = 8080
  processes = ["app"]
  protocol = "tcp"
  script_checks = []
  [services.concurrency]
    hard_limit = 25
    soft_limit = 20
    type = "connections"

  [[services.ports]]
    force_https = true
    handlers = ["http"]
    port = 80

  [[services.ports]]
    handlers = ["tls", "http"]
    port = 443

  [[services.tcp_checks]]
    grace_period = "1s"
    interval = "15s"
    restart_limit = 0
    timeout = "2s"
```

```
#-----procfile-----#

web: python db_script.py
```

the error message in the console was,

```
==> Creating release
--> release v4 created

--> You can detach the terminal anytime without stopping the deployment
==> Monitoring deployment
Logs: https://fly.io/apps/withered-snowflake-645/monitoring

 1 desired, 1 placed, 0 healthy, 1 unhealthy [restarts: 2] [health checks: 1 total]
Failed Instances

Failure #1

Instance
ID              PROCESS VERSION REGION  DESIRED STATUS  HEALTH CHECKS   RESTARTS        CREATED
4bdf42c6        app     4       fra     run     failed  1 total         2               21s ago

Recent Events
TIMESTAMP               TYPE            MESSAGE
2023-02-04T23:39:19Z    Received        Task received by client
2023-02-04T23:39:19Z    Task Setup      Building Task Directory
2023-02-04T23:39:24Z    Started         Task started by client
2023-02-04T23:39:26Z    Terminated      Exit Code: 0
2023-02-04T23:39:26Z    Restarting      Task restarting in 1.02248256s
2023-02-04T23:39:31Z    Started         Task started by client
2023-02-04T23:39:33Z    Terminated      Exit Code: 0
2023-02-04T23:39:33Z    Restarting      Task restarting in 1.047249935s
2023-02-04T23:39:39Z    Started         Task started by client
2023-02-04T23:39:41Z    Terminated      Exit Code: 0
2023-02-04T23:39:41Z    Not Restarting  Exceeded allowed attempts 2 in interval 5m0s and mode is "fail"
2023-02-04T23:39:41Z    Alloc Unhealthy Unhealthy because of failed task

2023-02-04T23:39:22Z   [info]Unpacking image
2023-02-04T23:39:23Z   [info]Preparing kernel init
2023-02-04T23:39:24Z   [info]Configuring firecracker
2023-02-04T23:39:24Z   [info]Starting virtual machine
2023-02-04T23:39:24Z   [info]Starting init (commit: e3cff9e)...
2023-02-04T23:39:24Z   [info]Preparing to run: `/cnb/process/web` as 1000
2023-02-04T23:39:24Z   [info]2023/02/04 23:39:24 listening on [fdaa:1:2a7f:a7b:b6:4bdf:42c6:2]:22 (DNS: [fdaa::3]:53)
2023-02-04T23:39:25Z   [info]Starting clean up.
2023-02-04T23:39:30Z   [info]Starting instance
2023-02-04T23:39:30Z   [info]Configuring virtual machine
2023-02-04T23:39:30Z   [info]Pulling container image
2023-02-04T23:39:31Z   [info]Unpacking image
2023-02-04T23:39:31Z   [info]Preparing kernel init
2023-02-04T23:39:31Z   [info]Configuring firecracker
2023-02-04T23:39:31Z   [info]Starting virtual machine
2023-02-04T23:39:31Z   [info]Starting init (commit: e3cff9e)...
2023-02-04T23:39:31Z   [info]Preparing to run: `/cnb/process/web` as 1000
2023-02-04T23:39:31Z   [info]2023/02/04 23:39:31 listening on [fdaa:1:2a7f:a7b:b6:4bdf:42c6:2]:22 (DNS: [fdaa::3]:53)
2023-02-04T23:39:32Z   [info]Starting clean up.
2023-02-04T23:39:37Z   [info]Starting instance
2023-02-04T23:39:38Z   [info]Configuring virtual machine
2023-02-04T23:39:38Z   [info]Pulling container image
2023-02-04T23:39:38Z   [info]Unpacking image
2023-02-04T23:39:38Z   [info]Preparing kernel init
2023-02-04T23:39:38Z   [info]Configuring firecracker
2023-02-04T23:39:39Z   [info]Starting virtual machine
2023-02-04T23:39:39Z   [info]Starting init (commit: e3cff9e)...
2023-02-04T23:39:39Z   [info]Preparing to run: `/cnb/process/web` as 1000
2023-02-04T23:39:39Z   [info]2023/02/04 23:39:39 listening on [fdaa:1:2a7f:a7b:b6:4bdf:42c6:2]:22 (DNS: [fdaa::3]:53)
2023-02-04T23:39:40Z   [info]Starting clean up.
--> v4 failed - Failed due to unhealthy allocations - no stable job version to auto revert to and deploying as v5    

--> Troubleshooting guide at https://fly.io/docs/getting-started/troubleshooting/
Error abort
```

[file directory of the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzZo3.png)

- I tried procfile with `worker: python db_script.py` it didn't work.
- `requirement.txt` file with and without codes of dependencies didn't work.
- By increasing the time of `time.sleep()` didn't work either.(tried for 5sec, 1hr)
- I want to know what is the reason for this error and how to solve it.

Can someone please help me troubleshoot this issue and find a solution to get my task running on Fly.io? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The fly.toml file seems to say that you are deploying a web application.  But your app is clearly not that.

Comment: This fly.toml file generated by flyctl and I didn't change anything in it. :(

Answer (score 0):

Open the log of your app in one terminal window by command below and try "fly deploy" in another window again. It allows us to see longer logs.
fly logs -a appname